# Unit testing: Emulate that user has specific calendar

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, swift4

I need to write tests for initialising `Date` objects, when user has, for example, *Buddhist* calendar and my formatter will have *Gregorian* calendar.

Date init function:

```
internal let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
private let formatter = DateFormatter()

init?(dateValue: String?, format: String) {
    guard let dateValue = dateValue else {
        return nil
    }

    formatter.dateFormat = format
    formatter.calendar = calendar
    guard let date = formatter.date(from: dateValue) else {
        return nil
    }

    self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: date.timeIntervalSince1970)
}
```

How can I setup user environment (calendar)? Like user has other than *Gregorian* calendar? Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Calendar.Identifier in your init. Something like this:

```
internal let calendar: Calendar
private let formatter = DateFormatter()

init?(dateValue: String?, format: String, calID: Calendar.Identifier = .gregorian) {
    guard let dateValue = dateValue else {
        return nil
    }

    self.calendar = Calendar(identifier: calID)
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    formatter.calendar = calendar
    guard let date = formatter.date(from: dateValue) else {
        return nil
    }

    self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: date.timeIntervalSince1970)
}
```

After that, when in Unit tests you init your class, you can pass needed Calendar.Identifier

Comment: I know, that I can just pass it to class. But I need simulate, that user has another calendar. In other words I need next: Calendar.current == Calendar(identifier: .buddhist). I need this condition to be true in tests